# python requests using magic mock, how to call the original method under some conditions

Tags: python, mocking

here the code to mock only a certain type of url

```
def mocked_requests_patch(*args, **kwargs):
    url = args[0]
    if url.find('additional_address') != -1:
        return 'mocked response'

    return requests.patch(*args, **kwargs)

requests.patch = MagicMock(side_effect=mocked_requests_patch)
```

but of course I'm getting a `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

saw some questions like this but didn't find any using `MagicMock`

Comment: why don't you first store `requests.patch` like `original_patch = requests.patch`?

Comment: worked . @Sraw write it as an answer and i'll accept. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not find an explicit question for this since it is relatively simple to save your own reference to a mocked method before installing a mock and in typical use a [patcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) is used to handle installing and un-installing the mock in a systematic manner via `start()` and `stop()`.

In this particular case since you're mocking `requests.patch` you may want to consider using the [requests_mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocker.html) package as it provides a mechanism to allow some requests to be sent to the real http method.  In fact you can see by inspecting the source how its `start()` [saves a reference](https://github.com/openstack/requests-mock/blob/master/requests_mock/mocker.py#L81) to the send function which is [later restored](https://github.com/openstack/requests-mock/blob/master/requests_mock/mocker.py#L122) by `stop()`